# Committing to a new Subversion branch

Tags: svn

This is probably a stupid question, but I haven't done this before in Svn.

I have a working copy of trunk on which I've been doing some heavy refactoring.  The trunk itself has moved on quite a bit in the meantime, and I'm not ready to merge yet.  I want to shelve my current changes to a new branch that doesn't yet exist.

What is the correct procedure here?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the revision of your working copy is based on:

```
svn info .
```

Copy that revision of trunk to a branch on the server with

```
svn copy svn://yourrepo/trunk svn://yourrepo/branches/a -r [revision]
```

and then switch your WC to the branch

```
svn switch svn://yourrepo/branches/a
```

Then you can commit your current changes to the branch.

Comment: Since the trunk has already moved on, and it's far from ready to merge; Probably want to add -r<rev> to the copy, where <rev> would be the rev. the local working copy is based on.

Comment: That's the key - thanks PtP.  How can I tell which version of the trunk I need to copy from?

Comment: `svn info .` should contain the rev. info

Answer (score 0):

In a couple of easy steps:

1) you must branch the trunk (that will require you to create a different folder in the repository for the new branch). If you use **Tortoise SVN** you just right click on the working folder and select `branch` in the Tortoise Svn submenu

2) on your working folder you must use the `switch` command to start working in the new branch. In **Tortoise** right click-> Switch and select the new branch

and you're working in a branch now

HTH, JP

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a very good question. What I would do in that scenario is create a branch not based from your current Working Copy but from the trunk revision when you made your Working Copy.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new branch folder.
2. Do an "svn info" and try to retrieve the Revision Number from when you made your Workng Copy of the Trunk. For instance, if you made the Working Copy on Rev 40 and the HEAD revision is now on 60, you need to use Rev 40 as a base revision of the new branch.
3. Do an "svn copy" and use that Revision Number when copying the Trunk revision to the new branch folder.
4. Do now an "svn checkout" of the new branch.
5. Copy the files from the Working Copy of the trunk to the Working Copy of the branch.
6. Commit the changes from the Branch Working Copy and scrap the Trunk working copy.

You should now have a new branch with your current changes that is based on the actual revision when you started your changes. Needless to say, that the new branch will be significantly out-dated and needs to be updated from the Trunk. You may postpone this until you are ready for a merge.

Comment: Thanks, this seems very similar to the accepted answer.  What is missing there?